# Squeeze right div into left div on phone

Tags: html, css

I tried to make my website switch layout based on the browser width like this:

Desktop view:

[image]

Mobile phone view:

[image]

I want the element on the right to be in the middle of the left two elements when viewed on phone. I tried to do it using pure CSS but can't figure out the right hierarchy. What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: Add some HTML so that we have something to work with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using classic floats within a media query to rearrange  your elements when viewport is above a certain point. You should use a *mobile first strategy* to keep things simple. The boxes stack in their natural order on mobile and you staart manipulating them into a column layout when reaching a certain viewport width.

```css
:root {
--blue:  #0074D9;
--green: #2ECC40;
--red:     #FF4136;
--white:  #FFFFFF;
--gray:   #AAAAAA;
--black:  #111111;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding: 1vw;
}

  .section--1 {
    background-color: var(--red);
  }

  .section--2 {
    background-color: var(--green);
  }

  .section--3 {
    background-color: var(--blue);
  }

@media (min-width: 480px) { 
  
  .section--1,
  .section--3 {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }

  .section--2 {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section class="section section--1">Element 1</section>
  <section class="section section--2">Element 2</section>
  <section class="section section--3">Element 3</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This example is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, you can use `media queries`
Here are some useful links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

If you look for a `framework`, take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I think media queries is the right way to go for my current project. Will try others, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 150px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    background:Orange;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: -220px 0px 0px 20px;
    height: 215px;
    }

@media (max-width: 699px) {
#ContentLeft1 {
    background: Yellow;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    background: Orange;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background: Blue;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 215px;
    }
}
</style>
<div id="ContentPanel1">
  <div id="ContentLeft1">
    element 1              
  </div>
  <div id="ContentMiddle1">
    element 2
  </div>
  <div id="ContentRight1">
    element 3            
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is really detailed.